# How can I customize a permission request popup for push notifications in a browser?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, web-worker

I see that some websites have a fancy push notification permission request popups like this one

[image]

whereas official API documentation doesn't provide any clue how to customize permission requests; and the only request I can generate looks like that

[image]

How can I create a less ugly popup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click the Allow button on the House of Bots site and you'll see exactly how they do it--they don't.

The pop-up you see is just plain html, nothing special. When you click allow, it opens a new window that asks for permission, and then you get the typical browser window just like in your second image.

Comment: Good to be aware - that still it's recommended - or at least worth consideration to use the customized pre-permissionrequest popups and to use them wisely. Some benefits explained here: https://uplandsoftware.com/localytics/resources/blog/using-in-app-messages-for-push-message-opt-ins/