# How to apply Custom Styles to Desktop notification

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

How to apply Custom Styles to Desktop notification Uisng Javascript

```
 Notification.requestPermission(function(status){

  if (status === "granted") {
   var  options = {
          type: "progress",
          body: "Text",   
      };
    var notification= new Notification("Hello",options);  
    setTimeout(function() { notification.close() },5000);
  }
});
 }
```

I tired Above code workig fine but I want apply background colour and some custom style. is it poosible?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I customize a permission request popup for push notifications in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841500/how-can-i-customize-a-permission-request-popup-for-push-notifications-in-a-brows)

Comment: i got notificaiton but i want apply styles to body and background-cloor